# (PowerShell Studio) Set specific column width for Out-String

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise, powershell-studio

I wanted to set specific column size. Below is the image-

[image]

Here I have set the width to be 150 & the command is-

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = "application"; StartTime = "10/30/2014 12:00:01 AM"; EndTime = "10/30/2014 11:59:59 PM" } | Select providername, timecreated, id, leveldisplayname, message | Format-Table | Out-String -Width 150
```

As you can see the Messages are getting trimmed and TimeCreated column  has lot of extra width. How can I set custom width for each column so that I can reduce the size for TimeCreated column and increase it for Message column.

Comment: try using the `-autosize` parameter of `format-table` and remove the `out-string` part. more info on formatting output: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347677.aspx

Comment: also using `-autosize` the last selected row might get truncated which in your example is the one you want to show fully, in the case autosize isnt making enough space you can use `-wrap` to show the full text for all columns

Comment: Thanks @Paul. Since I am using PowerShell Studio, I had to use Out-String so that the result can be displayed in TextBox. This worked for me- `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = "application"; StartTime = "10/30/2014 12:00:01 AM"; EndTime = "10/30/2014 11:59:59 PM" } | Select providername, timecreated, id, leveldisplayname, message | Format-Table -Wrap | Out-String -Width 120` Thanks

Comment: @paul good work i should have done that in my answer and you need to make that yours

Comment: i have added it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-wrap` parameter of `Format-Table` to disable trimming like so:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = "application"; StartTime = "10/30/2014 12:00:01 AM"; EndTime = "10/30/2014 11:59:59 PM" } | Select providername, timecreated, id, leveldisplayname, message | Format-Table -Wrap | Out-String -Width 120
```

to remove unneeded column spacing use the `-Autosize` parameter. Note that using `-Autosize` without `-wrap` will still shorten the last selected field if it's content is too long.

More info on Output Formatting using `Format-Table`:

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347677.aspx)